# Game Theory problem with n piles and 2 players, one player selects 2 piles, the other takes from one of them

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Player 'A' and player 'B' play with n piles of stones. 'A' starts the game. He chooses 2 piles, the 'B' takes an arbitrary (but nonzero) number of stones from one of them. Then 'B' selects two piles and 'A' takes some stones from one of them.
The player that removed the last stone wins.
Who has a winning strategy and what is it?

I tried using nim sums but not sure how to go on

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts, and for clarity ....what does "winning" mean?  Does "arbitrary" include $0$?

Comment: thanks you, I corrected it, if there are any other problems with the question please let me know

Answer (score -1):

Let W1 be the set of positions where you can take the last stone. Let L1 be the set of positions where you are forced to enter a state in W1. Let W2 be the set of positions where you can enter a state in L1, and so on.

Then find a pattern.

Comment: Yes I've tried that however I didn't manage to find the pattern. Could you help me a little with that?